# Is there a possibility to bind all private methods to class instance (aka. 'this') in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using this function to bind all public methods to 'this' (taken from here)
https://gist.github.com/anhldbk/782e13de7f79b07e556a029a9ce49fa3

```
static BindMethods() {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(this))
        .map(key => {
            if (this[key] instanceof Function && key !== 'constructor')
                this[key] = this[key].bind(this)
        })
}
```

Using like this and work as expected for public methods.

```
    class Test {
        constructor() {
            UTILS.BindMethods.call(this); // bind all to 'this' instance
        }

        Test() {
          // 'this' refers to instance as expected
          } 

        #MyPrivate() {
           // here 'this' still refers to caller context :(
        }
    }
```

I'm doing a project in NodeJs so I don't care about browsers, ECMA, etc.
I just need old fashion oop :)))

Is it possible to bind also my private methods to 'this' like above?

Thanks for hints!

EDIT:
Doesn't work for private when I call them by reference (ie. within a array of funcs).

Comment: How are you calling these functions? You shouldn't need to do anything this weird. Are you trying to create some kind of singleton?

Comment: see edited. by reference, within a array of funcs.

Comment: You're going to need to show an example of intent here. That could mean a lot of things. Can't you just use lambdas (e.g. arrow functions)?

Comment: Private methods don't exist really the way that named prototype properties do. There is no dynamic referencing, so the answer is very likely that you're stuck with `this.#privateVar = 5;` etc.

Comment: hmmm... I tried this.#MyPrivate.bind(this); and didn't work... you're right, I'm stuck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrow functions for private class field initialisation, if you really need one bound function object per instance. [The usual drawbacks](https://www.charpeni.com/blog/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think) don't really apply to private methods.

```
class Test {
    demo(arr) {
        return arr.map(this.#myPrivate);
    } 

    #myPrivate = () => {
         // here 'this' refers to the instance
    }
}
```

Comment: One question: Is there a considerable performance penalty using arrow funcs on private members compared to modify all over my code and try to use private as they are, but passing 'this' as argument (not sure now if I can, but just a question) ? Thanks!

Comment: You still haven't really shown in your question how you are calling them, so I can only speculate. Personally, I tend to not use private methods at all, unless I really have to. As for performance, it depends on what exactly the alternative is, and on how often each of the functions is constructed and called. I don't think it'll be noticeable in most cases, but [only you can know](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).